# What does guard mean in this situation?

Tags: vocabulary, british-english

> He [Harry] stopped a passing **guard**, but didn't dare mention
>   platform nine and three-quarters. The guard had never heard of
>   Hogwarts and when Harry couldn't even tell him what part of the
>   country it was in, he started to get annoyed, as though Harry was
>   being stupid on purpose.   
> (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

What does ‘guard’ mean: 9 or 20 [in a dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/guard?s=t) or any other?
9.a person or group of persons that guards, protects, or keeps a protective or restraining watch.
20. British . a railroad conductor.

Comment: It could be both. I would take _platform_ as meaning the part of the train station, and in that case _guard_ would mean "a railroad conductor." I find strange that the platform seems named after an hour, thought.

Comment: @kiamlaluno The platform number is a joke.  Railway platforms, at least in the UK, are generally numbered so you have Platform 1, Platform 2, etc.
The train to Hogwarts departs from a hidden platform between Platforms 9 & 10 known as Platform 9 and three quarters.

Comment: I guess that you read the book, since I don't get the joke from the few quoted sentences.

Comment: @kiamlaluno "Nine and three-quarters" is not a time designation in English. 9:45 would be "a quarter to [or til or of] ten.

Comment: @StoneyB That is why I wrote "seems named." `;)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of scope for confusion over this (British English) usage for the word *guard*, which isn't necessarily resolved by saying...

> BrE *guard* = AmE [conductor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Train_Conductor)
>    a railway train crew member responsible for operational and safety duties that do not involve actual operation of the train.
>
> (another AmE definition, from the [Railroad Jobs Guide](http://www.resumedictionary.com/railroad-jobs-resume/))
>    *Railroad conductors* examine schedules, switching orders, bill of ladings, and shipping records. On passenger trains they are responsible for the passengers and crew.

---

I'm not sure there *is* an AmE equivalent to BrE *guard* in this context. Essentially, **all** uniformed railway staff in the UK may be called *guards* - except when they're actually working on a train, in which case they're usually called *ticket inspectors* or sometimes *conductors* (or *drivers*, where appropriate, obviously!).

In OP's context, neither Harry (the fictional character) nor JK Rowling (the British author) would know or care exactly what job title the "guard" was actually employed as. So far as they're concerned, he's just any uniformed employee that passengers can reasonably treat as a representative of the company, when asking a simple railway-related question such as *"Where can I find the train to Hogwarts?"*.

---

TL;DR: BrE *guard* approximately corresponds to AmE *railroad conductor.* There's no special implication that any specific *guard* has any security-related duties, but obviously some do.

Comment: Thank you. The Korean translation book for Harry Potter translated ‘guard’ into ‘역무원’ [link](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1152&bih=749&q=%EC%97%AD%EB%AC%B4%EC%9B%90&oq=%EC%97%AD%EB%AC%B4%EC%9B%90&gs_l=img.3..0j0i24l2.1001.2432.0.2680.9.9.0.0.0.1.111.840.7j2.9.0...0.0...1ac.1j4.9.img.VvVNs5MtWRc)(station employees) – this is exactly the same as what you described in Korea. Before you gave your words, I still thought ‘역무원’ is the translator’s personal interpretation. Although there are lots of mistakes, she’s now given my one point owing to you.

Comment: @Listenever: You might need to bear in mind that both usage and the "real-world context" change over time. Some (mainly older) Brits might still call any uniformed rail employee *on the train* a "guard", but mainly that's a historical usage. Once he would have been the guy travelling on the [guard's van](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/guard's+van), but so far as I know we haven't had guard's vans on UK trains for many decades. The only employees we actually see on the train today are *ticket inspectors*.

Comment: "Essentially, all uniformed railway staff in the UK are called guards" - do you have anything to back that up? It's certainly not my experience as a native British English speaker.  A guard is one form of uniformed railway staff but certainly not the only one which the language recognises.

Comment: @Nigel: Per my last comment, both usage *and* the real world context change. I wouldn't be surprised to learn that there are in fact no workers officially classified as "guards" in the UK today (I haven't seen a guard's van in decades). But by the old "job-related" definition, guards travel on trains, so we shouldn't see any instances of ["a station guard"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+station+guard%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (they should be ***train** guards*)...

Comment: ...and you have to bear in mind this usage is from a *children's* book. Harry (and the intended readership) don't concern themselves with exact job descriptions. The man is in uniform, he works for the train company, and he's not the *train **driver***. He's "passing", so it's likely he works *at the station*, not on the train. Would you carp at me calling someone a "policeman" when in fact he's a "Police Community Support Officer"? You must surely expect that *children* in particular don't make such fine distinctions. OP asked what was **meant**, not whether it was **accurate**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree with you that the meaning in context is simply a uniformed rail employee of indeterminate function. However your answer goes beyond this context and claims that this usage is common in British English. This is what I question.  In my experience the term is generally used for someone with duties similar to an American train conductor and it is not common for other uniformed rail staff to be called guards.

Comment: @Nigel: Per my Wikipedia link, typical duties of American "conductor" include *Making sure the train stays on schedule. Ensuring that any cars and cargo are picked up and dropped off properly. Completing en-route paperwork. Ensuring the train follows applicable safety rules and practices. Controlling the train's movement while operating in reverse. Coupling or uncoupling cars. Assisting with setting out or picking up of rolling stock. Carrying out running repairs. **Ticket collection and other customer service duties**. Opening and closing train doors*. Pretty much everything except "driver"

Comment: @FumbleFingers That Wikipedia link also includes a description of British guards, strongly implying a similarity exists. It says "the person with ultimate responsibility for operation of a train is usually called the guard" and "Their jobs focused more on safe operation of their trains, timekeeping, handling parcels, and other consignments. A dedicated 'travelling ticket inspector' handled fare duties. In recent years, passenger train guards have been assigned more responsibility for on-train revenue collection and ticket inspection."

Comment: Enough already! I've changed ***are** called guards* to ***may be** called guards* (even though it's messed up my layout, which is why I used the shorter, less accurate, form in the first place! :)

Comment: +1 Whether or not OP got what she needed, ***I*** learned a lot from this answer.

Comment: @StoneyB: I almost feel I've *unlearned* something. When I first wrote this answer, I distinctly recall dithering for a bit before writing *or sometimes **conductors***. We definitely had conductors on buses (but not for years now). They really did "conduct", in that the driver always had to stop/start according to the conductor's signal. Anyway, I persuaded myself that we also had conductors on trains, even though it would be *signalmen* that did the controlling. Now I'm not sure if I'm not just recalling US usage (given none of this is "current" terminology).

Comment: "You have learned something. That always feels as if you have lost something." - *Bernard Shaw* ... But I can remember being confused by the term "guard" as a child reading British novels, until I realized that it meant "conductor". It was not until now that I discovered how much  a guard/conductor does in addition to punching tickets and discovering dead bodies in sleeping compartments.

Comment: @StoneyB: I commuted to school for years, the main consequence of which was that I became determined not to become a "commuter" in my later working life. Another thing a guard sometimes did was wake me up when the train reached its terminus. I'd have a *long* journey back up the line to school - hopelessly late, and desperately trying to think up a new excuse. Trains are Mogadon on steroids for me.

Answer (score 5):

Given the context (that Harry is in a station looking for a train) it's meaning 20, what is known in American English as a railroad conductor.  Obviously in this case one who is not currently on a train.

Answer (score 2):

Since the next sentence is "Getting desperate, Harry asked for the train that left at eleven o'clock, but the guard said there wasn't one." I would say that *guard* means "train conductor."
I imagine the protagonist is in a train station, and asks to the train conductor information about the trains.